# Datatables: referencing columns by names from a DOM datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Right now I have the following html table:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <th>fruits</th>
        <th>vegs</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>potato</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>carrot</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I'd like to reference the columns by name like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    /* Init the table */
    var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( );

    //get by sTitle
    console.log(oTable);
    var row = oTable.fnGetData(1)
    console.log(row['vegs']);//should return 'carrot'
} );
</script>
```

Is there anyway to have a javascript function `fnGetData()` to return an object rather than an array when the datasource is DOM?

Comment: Tricky. What should happen if you had two header cells with the same class/text value?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure but I guess that it would return the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've researched a bit and found the `datatable` plugin is not very smart at handling columns - they are always arrays needed to be accessed with an integer. The only thing that handles columns and their properties is the [`aoColumns` object](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) - thanks at @JustinWrobel for finding the `fnSettings` method to access that object after initialisation. If you haven't had this, you were stuck with `$table.find("thead th")`.

However, now it is easy to get the table as an array of objects:

```
var table = $mytable.dataTable(​…);
var cols = table.fnSettings().aoColumns,
    rows = table.fnGetData();

var result = $.map(rows, function(row) {
    var object = {};
    for (var i=row.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        // running backwards will overwrite a double property name with the first occurence
        object[cols[i].sTitle] = row[i]; // maybe use sName, if set
    return object;
});

result[1]["vegs"]; // "carrot"
```

Answer (score 2):

This has not been tested but may work:

```
$(function() {
    // Get an array of the column titles
    var colTitles = $.map($('#datatable th'), function() {
        return this.text();
    }).get();

    var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable();

    var row = oTable.fnGetData(1);
    console.log(row[colTitles.indexOf('vegs')]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [ShatyUT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408809/792789)'s answer and [fbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6155889/792789)'s I've come up with this:

```
$(function() {
   var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( );
   var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();  // you can find all sorts of goodies in the Settings

   var colTitles = $.map(oSettings.aoColumns, function(node) {
    return node.sTitle;
   });

   var row = oTable.fnGetData(1);
   console.log(row[colTitles.indexOf('vegs')]);
} );
```

But there has to be a better way...