# How to access hidden column in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a column named id in my datagrid. I have set `visible:false` for the field since I don't want to display the field in the grid.

But then how  can I get the value in id? any hope?
I am adding column as

```
columns.push({'sTitle':'id','visible': 'false'},{'sTitle':'name','visible': 'false'});
```

And I am retrieving the value in selected row as

```
this.$view.on("click",function(event){
    selectedRow = event.target.parentElement;
    var name = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Here in click event I can't get the value of id as html is not generated for the field with `visible:false`. So I am searching for a method to access my id field.

Comment: Can you post some code so it will be easier to see what the issue is.

Comment: + for code request. How do you generate the grid ?

Comment: columnDefs: [
          {field: 'empno', visible:false},
          {field:'name', visible:true}
          ]      .. So in my grid only name column is visible. The value in name field can be accessed from innerHTML .but how can i get the value in empno field ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display:none` property
-Edit:
In order to specify a custom css to your angular datagrid you should also specify the columns. Something like:

```
 $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    // ...
    columns: ['CompanyName', 'ContactName', 'City', 'Country']
});
```

[Here's the page I referenced to](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/UI_Widgets/Data_Grid/Visual_Elements/?version=14_2#UI_Widgets_Data_Grid_Visual_Elements_Grid_Columns_Specifying_Grid_Columns)
Edit2:

Since you're trying to retrieve the value of the field I would recommend you to take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911156/how-to-get-the-cell-value-from-ng-grid)

Comment: I should use  {field:'name', display:none } ?? .. I think diplay:none should be used in html??.But this is not my aim.

Comment: Yes! You are supposed to use it on the Column style.

Comment: Can you share some example code?I am using angular js datagrid .How can I set dispalay:none in that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You may wanna check if it's a valid answer.

Comment: I tried columns.push({'sTitle':'id','display': 'none'},{'sTitle':'name','display': 'none'}); but it doesn't work    but columns.push({'sTitle':'id','visible': 'false'},{'sTitle':'name','visible': 'true'}); is working fine for me.But when I set visible property the element is not accessable ..any help ?

Comment: You're working on the wrong side. You're trying to apply css properties on an angular side. It's better to keep them separeted. Specify your grid. Once you have your grid apply the css(`display:none`) on the column you need. Did you take a look at the page i linked on my answer?

Comment: I am very sorry to say that your answer doesnt helped me!! I am populating the datagrid by using a thirdparty tool so there is no way to add css in it.only property I can set is visible.I am following http://www.code-sample.com/2015/02/angularjs-ng-grid-hide-column.html  .   So here I am getting stuck on  how  I get the hidden columns value when I select some row ?Can you please look into this??

Comment: Actually the link reconnects to the same answer. My advice is to do it via CSS so you can later(at runtime) make it visible. Otherwise you can use the example code in the link you've posted me. Maybe if you poste some of your code, we can find the error

Comment: @Gino thanks for your help and response .I have edited my question with my codes .As of now I should stuck on the way I choose for some reason.Could you please check my edit and appreciate any help!!!!

Comment: After many reserch I solved the problem using built in DataTable function fnGetNodes() and  fnGetData() .Thanks agin for the support you have given!!!!! .The page I refrrenced is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384102/jquery-datatables-how-to-get-column-id